# Can I use a phone as bluetooth adapter?

Tags: hardware, android, bluetooth, iphone

I run Linux Mint 17 Qiana on an old Toshiba laptop that does not have a Bluetooth adapter. Is it possible to use a phone (coupled through usb) as bluetooth adapter in order to connect to an audio device? (preferably iPhone, but android would also be fine)

I tried googling, but I only get results on how to set up a bluetooth connection with a phone.

I realize this is a bit of a weird thing to ask, but due to an audio device with a broken wired connection, my being on holiday preventing me from buying a bluetooth adapter, and simple curiosity I would still like to know if this is possible ;)

Comment: You would need to run software on the phone to move the data from the USB connection to Bleutooth. Preferably such software would fake a USB audio module. I think it would be easier to insert a bluetooth dongle in the USB of your Toshiba laptop (5-10$), as you have USB free for that.